# Locate AirTags without iPad or iPhone

Tags: find-my, airtag

I lost my luggage that had an AirTag on it. However,  my only other Apple product, the iPad, was also in the luggage.

Find My through iCloud (https://icloud.com/find) doesn't list it.

I searched as much as I could, and it really seems that Find My for AirTags only works with iOS

I have a MacBook, but my MacBook is logged in with a different ID than my iPad.

I also tried https://www.icloud.com/find using the same login info as my iPad, but none of my AirTags are listed, just my devices

[![Find My Map][1]][1]

Am I out of luck ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of the date of this answer, Apple doesn't include AirTags in the list of items you can locate on iCloud.com.

Your only option is to 'borrow' a different Apple device (Mac, iPhone, iPad), log in using your Apple ID, try to [locate the AirTag](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/locate-an-item-ipha779f0c10/ios), then log out of your ID on the device.

Comment: Depending on where you live the police may be happy to help you and may be in possession of Apple devices.